# Font weight difference between two computers with the same OS and browser version

Tags: css, fonts

I've got text on a website that is styled with the CSS rule:

```
font-weight:normal;
```

When viewing it through Chrome version 25.0.1364.99 on my local machine that is running MacOS 10.7.5 the font looks normal, but when viewing it from a different computer with the same OS version, same Chrome version, and same font set the text looks abnormally thin.

Is there something other than styling and font that could be affecting how the font is rendered in the browser??

Comment: Different operating systems format text differently; there's no real way to ensure it will look exactly the same without doing nasty hacks where you detect the specific browser version and OS and give respective CSS code.

Comment: It could be that one computer has a program which replaced some fonts.

Comment: @ChristianStewart - Yeah I expect it to look kind of different between OSs, but the odd thing is that this is a difference between the same OS version.

Comment: @mddw - Good point, I'll look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure they both have LCD font smoothing set. This can make a difference in how a font looks visually. This can affect some fonts more than others, so the system font may look the same between the two, while the one you're using may look different. Also, if one screen is much higher quality, this setting can have a more profound effect, but they still may look different (e.g. retina vs non-retina).

On 10.8 this setting is under System Preferences, General.

> [image: setting]

Comment: Both computers have LCD font smoothing set. Your point about the display types might be it. The computers that show it as bold are both a couple of years old and the ones that are showing it as normal are from 2012. I'll follow up on this a bit more. Thanks for the tip

Comment: The display difference ended up not being the issue. We were, however, able to get a consistant look after looking into the font smoothing. In the end we added a css rule of "-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;" which got the font weight to look consistant between the computers. Thank's for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```
 font-smoothing:antialiased;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that one of the operating systems has different accessibility or display options. Check out the font options under the display settings. That could be your culprit.